# Can I make a property to apply only to selected child elements?

Tags: css

Say for example I have the following code!

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__first">I am a box maybe!</div>
    <div class="container__second">I am a circle maybe!</div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden; /*How can I make it so this property only applies to container__first but not 
                      the second*/
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. **What are you trying to achieve?**

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with `:nth-child()`, select the div after .container with `.container div` and in the `:nth-child()` you can select wich child to select.

```css
.container div:nth-child(1) {
        overflow: hidden; /*How can I make it so this property only applies to container__first but not */
        background: green;            /*     the second*/
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="container__first">I am a box maybe!</div>
        <div class="container__second">I am a circle maybe!</div>
    </div>
```

**edit** the easiest way would be just styling on `.container__first{}` or `.container .container__first{}` if only selecting that child is what you need.

Comment: Why not just use the childs' class names, though?

Comment: in this case `.container .container__first` would've worked too, but i assumed OP was looking for something other then that, being able to select more children at once, leaving some out

Answer (score 0):

If you've already set the classes, container_first and container_second, you could just set different properties in the CSS. Just to make it simple, I'll make the text in first container bolded and the text in the second container italicized. See:

```css
.container__first {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container__second {
    overflow: visible;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__first">I am a box maybe!</div>
    <div class="container__second">I am a circle maybe!</div>
</div>
```

---

If you don't want to assign classes, there are a few other options. Like @ramon-de-vires said above, you could assign an `:nth-child` or `:last-child` node to the last child (or a specific child) in the CSS, as shown:

```css
.container p {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.container p:last-child {
    overflow: visible;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>I am a box maybe!</p>
    <p>I am a circle maybe!</p>
</div>
```

---

Possibly the easiest way, though, is to utilize an `!important` declaration, which overrides and ignores subsequent styling rules in the CSS. Just add `!important` after the parameter of any property (but before the `;`) to indicate that the values should supersede values defined elsewhere.